# Style a Specfic Column of a specific Row of a Table

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

## I have

a table

[image]

---

## I want

to style a specific td of a specific row of a table.

---

## I decided

to loop through each `row`, in each row, I loop through each `td`, and check if that `td` is equal to the one I want to check.

---

## I tried

```
$('#account-table').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
      var td = $(this);
      if(td.innerText == 'vazogaxan@hotmail.com'){
        $(this).css('color','red');
      }
   
    });
});
```

---

## I got

I couldn't get that column text to be **red**.

Any hints / suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerText` is a vanilla JS property, but you have a jQuery object and you try to access a inexistent property. Use `text()` method instead

```
 if(td.text() == 'vazogaxan@hotmail.com'){
```

More info:

http://api.jquery.com/text/

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

Comment: I'm faster this time `:)` . Glad to see you, @Harry

Comment: It works. I'll accept your answer in 2 mins. Thanks for your helps.